# django_social_auth exception after successful log in

Tags: django, django-socialauth, pinax

I have added Facebook integration into my site, and trying to login using a Facebook account and it fails after successful log in at(/account/social/complete/facebook/) with a Name Error.

Exception Type: NameError at /account/social/complete/facebook/
Exception Value: global name 'Profile' is not defined

Traceback: https://dpaste.de/MzUx

My profiles model class is called UserProfile and not Profile, however I can't see where django_social_auth is calling this from.

Also my project is based on pinix-project-social at https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-social

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is not within ``django-social-auth``, the traceback shows that the error happens when the ``post_signal`` is triggered by Django, so there must be something around (either your project code or any of the ``INSTALLED_APPS``), that's listening for that signal and trying to use a ``Profile`` class that's not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in my source files or libraries so I decided to try clear all my .pyc files and this fixed the NameError issue.